# Trying to access associative arrays inside ajax success response

Tags: jquery, json, flask

I am attempting to loop over a list which contains associative arrays with keys and values.

```
            console.log(response)
            response = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.data)
            $.each(response, function(k, v) {
                 console.log(k + " : " + v)
            });
```

**EDIT: Errors**

[image]

Comment: have you tried using $.each before executing stringify ? it  is no longer an array but a string i think once you have executed this

Comment: @ArpitBansal, I have tried a lot of things, feel free to explain more. Thx.

Comment: @ArpitBansal, see my console.logs. Once stringified it outputs a list as the one below the `Array [{}]` print out.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of expanded "Array [ {...} ]" from the console.

Comment: @JohnSmith Try to make a snippet example with that array.

Comment: @SilverSurfer, please explain?

Comment: @SilverSurfer, I am getting `SyntaxError: nothing to repeat` now.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error in a snippet code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: Thanks for the edited screenshot. I have added a snippet for each element. it might be a little different from what you want but it does loop through every element in the array @John Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because the array is no longer an array but a string

```js
response = [{category_id:2,name:"Quantum Computing"},{category_id:2,name:"John Smith"}];  

console.log(response);
    
response.forEach(function(element){
  var elementList = Object.keys(element);
  elementList.forEach(function (ele){
    console.log(ele+" "+element[ele]);
  });
  console.log(element.name)
});
```

Does this look like what you want to achieve.

Comment: But, I want the keys and values, so that I can replace them in a template. Thx.

Comment: Made some changes to it. Can you check if it satisfies your condition?

Comment: JSON.stringify will work but then you have to start treating it as a string and make necessary changes to consume it as a string. A better option is to use it as an Array as such. Did the solution work ?

Comment: "A better option is to use it as an Array as such.", show me an example!

Comment: It is what i have done in my response. I have used the various properties of an Array and not used string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201585/discussion-between-arpit-bansal-and-john-smith).